# Pinterest Android SDK / Callback after successful pin?

Tags: android, sdk, pinterest

Fellow SO members,

I am trying to figure out how to get a callback from the Android Pinterest SDK, after a "pin it" event has successfully completed. I have implemented the SDK as follows:

> ```
>         PinIt pinIt = new PinIt();
>         pinIt.setUrl(socialContent.getLink());
>         pinIt.setImageUrl(socialContent.getPicture());
>         pinIt.setDescription(socialContent.getMessage());
>         pinIt.setListener(new PinItListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onStart() {
>                 super.onStart();
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public void onComplete(boolean completed) {
>                 super.onComplete(completed);
>                 if (completed) {
>                     handle Pin It form displayed=true event
>                 }
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public void onException(Exception e) {
>                 super.onException(e);
>                 exception handling code...
>             }
>         });
>         pinIt.doPinIt(getActivity());
> ```

Per the documentation, onComplete(true) gets called as soon as the Pin It form comes up. What I'm looking for is a way to get a callback when the "Pin It" event is successfully completed. So far, I have found now way to do this.

My iOS co-worker found that there was a way to register an app URI ("yourapp://blah") as a form of callback. I have found no such way to do this in the Android Pinterest SDK.

Does anyone know how to receive an event after the "Pin It" event is successfully completed?

Comment: Hi, did you found any clue? I'm in the situation now...

Comment: @Woody No, I wish I did. I tried reaching out to Pinterest through their help desk and also tried reaching out to the SDK developer directly. Nobody has responded to me, and there have been no new updates to the SDK. Please let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: I will, thanks for the response.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? This is about the only thread where someone has addressed this conflict. Opening up the Pin It window is not the same as completing an action. Any fixes to this?

Comment: I never did find a solution, and I never could reach anyone within Pinterest who could help. Kind of a bummer.